# Adding “null” by default using drived transformation

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a sql table which data type is int and it doesn’t accept null value.

So what I want to do is add “null” using derived column.

What I did is used drived transformation and add a new column and use expression (DT_WSTR,10) “null”

And then used data conversion and changed the data type into DT_14 but the data conversion fails upon execution.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why not just drop the `not null` constraint?

Comment: I can’t do that, that was my first thought too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're trying to do. An `INTEGER NOT NULL` column will throw an error if you try to insert a text value into it, as you've seen.

There are really only two options.

1. Insert a zero for any `NULL` values that come through.
2. Insert a dummy value that's out of the range of values for the column, such as `999999` or the minimum or maximum values for an integer data type.

Or, of course, as Gordon suggested in the comments, drop the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column and insert the `NULL` values.

Comment: I like using a series of negative values which provide their own meaning like -1 is null, -2 is not valid, etc

Comment: I typically do this for dimension keys